# Mongodb repair database return: Invalid access at address: 0, Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault)

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Everything was working fine for few months and then I upgraded my docker version and then something was crashed.

There was a lot of problem like access rights, docker machines etc but then I realise that I have to repair database by `mongod --repair` and it is necessary and last hope.

What I want to achieve is to restore database that weight about 1.6gb and one of collection has 26millions of rows of Forex data historical prices and this collection matter the most for me.

I have tried `docker-compose up --build` with:

- various version of mongo image (3.6 - used before, latest and recommended by mongo developers - 4.0),
- I also tried run repair with specified path of stored data `mongo --repair --dbpath /data/db --storageEngine wiredTiger` as well
- various directory access and permission for directory that store data `/data/db` and it isn't directory permission or access issue since I fixed it and got another error.
- removing Docker: images, containers, volumes, machines - like I was using Docker from scratch
- creating new database by the same Dockerfile, docker-compose but with another Volume. Creating new directory and add this to volume work properly but my database is empty of course. But hence I am certain that damaged old data is my problem.

But None of these work properly so I have to ask you.

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./database/db3:/data/db
      - ./docker-entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 27022:27017
    command: mongod --repair --dbpath /data/db --storageEngine wiredTiger

  db_filler:
    build: .
    container_name: db_filler
    image: db_filler
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    links:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
```

My `docker-entrypoint.sh` where I set access to user `mongodb` to be able to write some data

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- mongod "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'mongod' ]; then
    chown -R mongodb /data/db

    numa='numactl --interleave=all'
    if $numa true &> /dev/null; then
        set -- $numa "$@"
    fi

    exec gosu mongodb "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

My `Dockerfile` (I paste it since docker-compose used this Dockerfile but I think it doesn't change anything):

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./backtest .
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

How do you think: can it be caused because of trying to process (copy, indexing, move, repair, etc - I don't know how --repair process going) collection that is too heavy and has too much rows so some timeout or lack of resources occur ?  First log indicate that some of recourses are used for this operation

While processing `repair` on my database I got following traceback:

```
mongo_1      | 2019-01-27T13:55:15.187+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]   building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
mongo_1      | 2019-01-27T13:55:15.212+0000 W ASIO     [initandlisten] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
mongo_1      | 2019-01-27T13:55:15.236+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Invalid access at address: 0
mongo_1      | 2019-01-27T13:55:15.259+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
mongo_1      |  0x55a2ac8b82e1 0x55a2ac8b74f9 0x55a2ac8b7b66 0x7ff9a0cf5390 0x55a2ac0fbfbc 0x55a2ac0eae31 0x55a2ac0ef5f7 0x55a2ac0ef781 0x55a2ab2c42c7 0x55a2ac1f5528 0x55a2abe0da1b 0x55a2ab74abdb 0x55a2ab3cb78f 0x55a2ab3d1b8a 0x55a2aae64437 0x55a2aaf4c97b 0x55a2aaee25a9 0x7ff9a093a830 0x55a2aaf4aae9
mongo_1      | ----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
mongo_1      | {"backtrace":[{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"23EB2E1","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"23EA4F9"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"23EAB66"},{"b":"7FF9A0CE4000","o":"11390"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"1C2EFBC","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor18NetworkInterfaceTL8shutdownEv"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"1C1DE31","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor5_joinESt11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"1C225F7","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutorD1Ev"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"1C22781","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutorD0Ev"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"DF72C7"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"1D28528","s":"_ZN5mongo23CollectionShardingState3getEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_15NamespaceStringE"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"1940A1B","s":"_ZN5mongo31AutoGetCollectionForReadCommandC1EPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_21NamespaceStringOrUUIDENS_17AutoGetCollection8ViewModeENS_6Date_tE"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"127DBDB","s":"_ZN5mongo7Helpers12getSingletonEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjE"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"EFE78F"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"F04B8A","s":"_ZN5mongo30repairDatabasesAndCheckVersionEPNS_16OperationContextE"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"997437"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"A7F97B","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"A155A9","s":"main"},{"b":"7FF9A091A000","o":"20830","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"55A2AA4CD000","o":"A7DAE9","s":"_start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "4.0.5", "gitVersion" : "3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.9.125-linuxkit", "version" : "#1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "55A2AA4CD000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D2BD849936E6F1CDEAA6678F57E07D725B522378" }, { "b" : "7FFC11975000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AA3586244F239D468C9D9083DA99D53FE1408277" }, { "b" : "7FF9A20F5000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E2D1DB1857AE8F07908959381751796E89FF56BB" }, { "b" : "7FF9A1EDA000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6EF73266978476EF9F2FD2CF31E57F4597CB74F8" }, { "b" : "7FF9A1A95000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8942CA58A3B910E883CC31E04A23DBD09729B4B0" }, { "b" : "7FF9A182C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "473092A9AF373FB0CAB555F9A003BC67F47756B6" }, { "b" : "7FF9A1628000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8CC8D0D119B142D839800BFF71FB71E73AEA7BD4" }, { "b" : "7FF9A1420000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "89C34D7A182387D76D5CDA1F7718F5D58824DFB3" }, { "b" : "7FF9A1117000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DFB85DE42DAFFD09640C8FE377D572DE3E168920" }, { "b" : "7FF9A0F01000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7FF9A0CE4000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CE17E023542265FC11D9BC8F534BB4F070493D30" }, { "b" : "7FF9A091A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B5381A457906D279073822A5CEB24C4BFEF94DDB" }, { "b" : "7FF9A2364000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D7B6259552275A3C17BD4C3FD05F5A6BF40CAA5" }, { "b" : "7FF9A06E7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E09D3783AD1D0BBCD3204FA01E4EF6D756E18F57" }, { "b" : "7FF9A04CB000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D1CC1204D6B6D33BD1D2C5A2A0516A2234322CF" }, { "b" : "7FF9A0281000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "41971A4A3CCDC54A447F41DF4BD96C948C546E0E" }, { "b" : "7FF9A0072000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5B146086EC173C299BA45F0C92E068D68CC7AD37" }, { "b" : "7FF99FE21000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D02A94DB90567C2C45F40C8565809A041FD22A55" }, { "b" : "7FF99FC07000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D9BD4CE26E45EF16075C67D5F5EEAFD8B562832" }, { "b" : "7FF99F8D7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3CE893F6D1382C2C7648DCCB06E71B1C7E0861CC" }, { "b" : "7FF99F6A4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B11678F560199547DCF726384EA39153EE0DFABF" }, { "b" : "7FF99F46E000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D6B36C5A463EE0FA84FDD6D5FD3F7726EDB90D54" }, { "b" : "7FF99F1EE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7B3533D5998D20EE1A1BE3F87789B69041E7F620" }, { "b" : "7FF99EF1C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0EEF7058B0737B68BDF89E5DC604D0AC389C8BB1" }, { "b" : "7FF99ECED000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FFBA483A43D9EF73925AC116811890C037523DA1" }, { "b" : "7FF99EAE9000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1E16CB57F699E215A2A8D4EFEF90883BC749B12D" }, { "b" : "7FF99E8DE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B789D8D4B4FC333405AB34387D9237F954060EA4" }, { "b" : "7FF99E6C3000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "87783DF8A1058CD150F8886CB36340384093C18F" }, { "b" : "7FF99E482000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1FE877BE52A424D0636AFD4D35BB330E41D6E0F3" }, { "b" : "7FF99E21E000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A0E2D03FF5CF65937F4425D4EFD4D655243809EB" }, { "b" : "7FF99E00B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E07E186694852D8F69459C6AB28A53F8DA3CE3B6" }, { "b" : "7FF99DE07000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3364D4BF2113C4E8D17EF533867ECC99A53413D6" }, { "b" : "7FF99DBFE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "73A8EADBC85860662B24850E71D4AFBE22C33359" }, { "b" : "7FF99D974000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "59E742306A4EA2872E061ECCE92F35FADDA75357" }, { "b" : "7FF99D6D2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E5C159E415406AE79D21056D752BA949C408B5B1" }, { "b" : "7FF99D49F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7D15576E1F096614D360784E4A01A1F5FAF908C9" }, { "b" : "7FF99D289000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "481DB33C28D88E43DA6BED65E1A7599407D4D818" }, { "b" : "7FF99D081000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9D9C958F1F4894AFEF6AECD90D1C430EA29AC34F" }, { "b" : "7FF99CE58000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "57E25072866B2D30CF02EBE7AE623B84F96FA700" }, { "b" : "7FF99CC49000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F6F1B4E9F89B716C4A0BA5819BDFFAF4A13EFB91" }, { "b" : "7FF99C9FE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C60082E3BB78D0D42868D9B359B89BF66CE5A1A7" }, { "b" : "7FF99C729000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D9782BA023CAEC26B15D8676E3A5D07B55E121EF" }, { "b" : "7FF99C4F1000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7BDD51353D50310FFA1587E4AA01B40ABE32D582" } ] }}
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55a2ac8b82e1]
mongo_1      |  mongod(+0x23EA4F9) [0x55a2ac8b74f9]
mongo_1      |  mongod(+0x23EAB66) [0x55a2ac8b7b66]
mongo_1      |  libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7ff9a0cf5390]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor18NetworkInterfaceTL8shutdownEv+0xDC) [0x55a2ac0fbfbc]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor5_joinESt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x421) [0x55a2ac0eae31]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutorD1Ev+0x67) [0x55a2ac0ef5f7]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutorD0Ev+0x11) [0x55a2ac0ef781]
mongo_1      |  mongod(+0xDF72C7) [0x55a2ab2c42c7]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo23CollectionShardingState3getEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_15NamespaceStringE+0x98) [0x55a2ac1f5528]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo31AutoGetCollectionForReadCommandC1EPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_21NamespaceStringOrUUIDENS_17AutoGetCollection8ViewModeENS_6Date_tE+0xBB) [0x55a2abe0da1b]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo7Helpers12getSingletonEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjE+0x11B) [0x55a2ab74abdb]
mongo_1      |  mongod(+0xEFE78F) [0x55a2ab3cb78f]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo30repairDatabasesAndCheckVersionEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x5EA) [0x55a2ab3d1b8a]
mongo_1      |  mongod(+0x997437) [0x55a2aae64437]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_+0x10DB) [0x55a2aaf4c97b]
mongo_1      |  mongod(main+0x9) [0x55a2aaee25a9]
mongo_1      |  libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF0) [0x7ff9a093a830]
mongo_1      |  mongod(_start+0x29) [0x55a2aaf4aae9]
mongo_1      | -----  END BACKTRACE  -----
forex_bot_mongo_1 exited with code 139
```

Comment: Problem occurred second time.  I REALLY don't reccomend mongodb